# MySQL Workbench import issues

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a .sql file, that contains a database with tables and records within the tables, the problem is that when I import it, Workbench only shows me the table models but not the records (inserts, the inserts tab in workbench is empty for all of my tables). I checked on PHPMyAmdin and I can see the records, but I need to use them in Workbench, Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where you import the sql file, but I assume you want to load the script into a real db but have used the modeling reverse engineering feature.

Instead open a connection to your server via the home screen (you have to have a connection tile created for that already) and then use the toolbar button "Open a script file in this editor" to load that script. You can then run it creating and filling so your db. Make a schema the default by double clicking it in the tree on the left if your script does not use qualified names.

[image]